# Openiddict NET 4.8 ASP WebForm client, OWIN startup implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, owin, openiddict

Implemented Server Client Authorization based on recent Velusia example taken from here: [openiddict-samples](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples)

all ASP NET.CORE clients work fine, but unfortunately I have to implement token authorization flow for some old ASP NET 4.8 Web form applications.

Added following OWIN startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    // These values are stored in Web.config. Make sure you update them!
    private readonly string _clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

    private readonly string _redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];
    private readonly string _authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthUrl"];
    private readonly string _clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = _clientId,
            ClientSecret = _clientSecret,
            Authority = _authority,
            RedirectUri = _redirectUri,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code, 
            Scope = $"{OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId} profile {OpenIdConnectScope.Email} roles",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name" , RoleClaimType = "role"},
            CallbackPath = new PathString("//"), //signin-oidc

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
                    {
                        Address = _authority + "/connect/token",
                        ClientId = _clientId,
                        ClientSecret = _clientSecret,
                        Code = n.Code,
                        RedirectUri = _redirectUri
                    });

                    if (!tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>()
                        {
                            new Claim("id_token", tokenResponse.IdentityToken),
                            new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken)
                        };

                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaims(claims);
                    }
                },
            },
        });
    }
}
```

behind the login button following code:

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
```

initially it starts fine, click on the login button and request goes to the server, I can see server login page. Once the password is entered request comes back to the client and opens following page: https://localhost/signin-oidc ...  and I never get AuthorizationCodeReceived  event triggered!

Anybody tried something similar?

Comment: Hello
I have the same problem. Could you solve it?